# jQuery - passing variable to event by data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create some objects dynamically and bind events to them (not important what events).

I'm passing a number to the event in order to distinguish those items. There is my code:

```
$('#add_btn').click(function() {
    var cont = $('#buttons');

    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        var new_btn = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val(i);

        new_btn.click(function() {
            alert(i);
        });

        cont.append(new_btn);
    }
});
```

When I click on any from newly created buttons, displayed number is 5.

I think that `i` variable is passing by reference, but the question is: how to avoid passing variable by reference? More, even if I crate new variable before binding event (so the reference should point to another object, for example `new_val = i.toString()`), value is still same for all buttons (then its 4, understandable).

I know that I can attach `new_btn.data()` and read it in event, but I'm not sure if it won't be an overhead.

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jner6/5/.

Comment: Famous question: [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Scope... that is all.

Comment: Thank you all for responses, closure is the keyword ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) [scoped variable in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake), inside the loop you need to create a private closure.

```
$('#add_btn').click(function () {
    var cont = $('#buttons');

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            var new_btn = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val(i);

            new_btn.click(function () {
                alert(i);
            });

            cont.append(new_btn);
        })(i)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you run into closures issue, try this:

```
(function( i ) {
    new_btn.click(function() {
        alert(i);
    });
})( i );
```

This will create immediate invoked function that will closure your variable `i` so you can use it in future. For now you just overriding `i` variable in your for-loop so you will have always same value that will equal last for-loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make functions within a loop.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/Omemaz/4/edit)**

```
var cont = $('#buttons');

$('#add_btn').click(function() {

    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
      $('<input>', {type:'button', value:i}).appendTo( cont );
    } 

});

cont.on('click', ':button', function() {
    alert( this.value );
});
```